# libpulseaudio playback / ui synchronization

Tags: pulseaudio

I have successfully setup pulse audio asynchronous playback stream using `pa_stream_connect_playback()` call.

Now I am facing a problem of synchronizing my UI with the playback.
In my render loop I need to estimate current playing sample from the beginning of playback:

```
loop {
  let current_sample = ???

  // handle inputs and render UI synchronized to current_sample
}
```

I tried to use `pa_stream_get_timing_info().read_index` but it jumps in big increments.

What is the best strategy to have good synchronization?

Should I query `pa_stream_get_timing_info` on every frame and use current latency as a compensation for current clock read instead? This gets especially complicated in the presence of `pa_stream_cork` calls and occasional underflows.

Is there a more precise way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the `pa_stream_get_time` function. Its implementation has all the details I need.